# How to query specific sheet in Google sheets API using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, google-sheets

I can access a range of cells from the default first sheet using:

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet_id + '/gviz/tq?range=C3:C100';
$.ajax(url).done(function(result){
....
```

But this only gives the first sheet. How can I access the other sheets in the spreadsheet? I would think it's another parameter option at the end of the url (where it says "?range=C3:C100")

Answer (score 1):

Using [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) like `Sheet2!A1:B2` or `'my sheet'!A1:B2` in the range parameter works.  Using the the spreadsheet used in mapbox's sheets integration demo, [...tq?range=C3:C4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16fTFtrVyW6zunP0fow5jZaupEkKA-MSMvtQQLp3-tQY/gviz/tq?range=C3:C4) yields the same result as [...tq?range=Demo!C3:C4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16fTFtrVyW6zunP0fow5jZaupEkKA-MSMvtQQLp3-tQY/gviz/tq?range=Demo!C3:C4). However, these results are in a custom mime type. For pure JSON, use the the sheets api v4 value GET endpoint : `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}` (docs [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)).  I'd highly recommend their API explorer, which shows exactly the results you would get from a query.